# When navigation View item cover with background blue on click in android?

Tags: android

I have a navigation View in my main activity and have some items, problem is that when I click item item name field get filled with blue background.How can I resolve that

code:-

```
NavigationView m_Navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    m_Navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_wallet) {
        // Handle the camera action
        Intent wallet = new Intent(this, CMyWalletScreen.class);
        startActivity(wallet);
    } else if (id == R.id.referandEarn) {
        Intent refer = new Intent(this, CReferAndEarnScreen.class);
        startActivity(refer);
    } else if (id == R.id.myProfile) {
        Intent profile = new Intent(this, CMyProfile.class);
        startActivity(profile);
    } else if (id == R.id.setting) {
        Intent setting = new Intent(this, CSettingScreen.class);
        startActivity(setting);
    } else if (id == R.id.LogOut) {
        showdialog();
    }
    m_Drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

style file:-

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/primary_dark</item>

</style>
```

Comment: its configured in its style file not here show your `styles.xml` file?

Comment: I added style file kinldy view

Comment: add full file and also colors ? what color you want to show on clicked?

Comment: I dont' want to show any color on click

Comment: its feature in latest android os called ripple effect.

Comment: show your main activty xml code where navigation drawer is added.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is solve :

Your xml file in change

//Add this line in header

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

//after add this code in navigation view

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/drawer_item" />
```

// after create folder res/color

// after create file res/color/drawer_item.xml

//Add this code in drawer_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:state_checked= "true"
        android:drawable="#0098D9"/> //your color code
    <item
        android:color="@android:color/white"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
</selector>
```